# Odd process appearing about every 18-20 minutes that runs 'apt-get --just-print dist-upgrade'

Tags: debian, cron, process

Got this process running on a 4 core Virtual Machine server running Debian 11 that pops up about every 20 minutes:

```
/usr/bin/apt-get --just-print dist-upgrade
```

...and I'd like to stop it as this VM server is really not meant to be upgraded, certainly not every 20 minutes!  At the most it sucks down a whole core at 100% for about 20-30 seconds while I'm trying to run other services or intense grep/find searches through various files.

Unattended upgrades is not installed, there is no service running for apt or cron-apt or unattended-upgrades, I find no entry in cron-apt that has 'just-print' as an option and 'dist-upgrade' entries in cron-apt are disabled, and there are no cron entries running every 20 minutes.  Oh, and nothing appears regarding dist-upgrade in the history log for apt.

cron-apt documentation isn't much help - there isn't even mention of the 'just-print' option, so I do not currently think it is a cron-apt issue.

I'm a bit perplexed.  Any tips on where to look for this entry and disable it are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably a systemd timer then? You can use `pstree` or `htop` to see the parent process.

Comment: @Halfgaar - pstree did the trick - was able to catch the errant process when it struck again.   will post as an answer for other confused people.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Halfgaar, using `pstree` when the process reappeared revealed its parents, and as a result I could use that info to find what was running that command.

```
cims@cimsserver:/home/cims$ pstree -p -s
systemd(1)─┬─PM2 v4.2.3: God(1082)─┬─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1083)
           │                       ├─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1084)
           │                       ├─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1085)
           │                       ├─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1086)
           │                       ├─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1087)
           │                       ├─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1088)
           │                       ├─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1318)
           │                       ├─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1319)
           │                       ├─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1320)
           │                       └─{PM2 v4.2.3: God}(1321)
           ├─VGAuthService(541)
           ├─agetty(966)
           ├─bash(558872)─┬─apt.sh(558874)───apt.sh(558877)─┬─apt-get(558879)
           │              │                                 ├─awk(558880)
           │              │                                 ├─awk(558883)
           │              │                                 ├─sort(558881)
           │              │                                 └─uniq(558882)
           │              └─sponge(558875)
```

That last `apt-get` caught my eye (as it was the only thing running while I was watching htop), and finding the apt.sh file that was using it led me to the shell script that was running that command.

```
cims@cimsserver:/home/cims$ locate apt.sh
/usr/share/prometheus-node-exporter-collectors/apt.sh
```

Which turned out to be a Prometheus script that was meant to expose metrics from apt updates and gets sent to my Grafana server - just never used.

Thanks again to @Halfgaar for the `pstree` tip.  Saved me some headaches. :)

Comment: aw.  I can't accept my own answer :(

Comment: now to figure out how to kill it!   renaming the .sh file should do for now.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Had you not been able to find where `apt.sh` was, something like `ps axjf` would have shown where it was (full command path).

Comment: @thedigitalmouse probably 48h delay ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work )